# How to reveal storyboard elements

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

An iOS developer designed a simple unit conversion app for me in Swift, consisting of one view which converts units of weight on the left side into different units of weight on the right side (eg kilograms into pounds). I now want to extend it so that it has another view, one dealing with volumes.

I'm trying to understand what the developer did so that I can repeat it and create this 2nd view. Is there a way to click on an element in the storyboard and see exactly what it is?

For example, in the image below is there a way I can click on the blue line that runs from the Navigation Controller to the Mass Unit Converter and see the exact properties of that element?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The information shows up in the Inspector panel, to the right. There are several tabs there, look through them and you will learn all you want about these elements.